In John 16:13 τὸ πνεῦμα is neuter; why is ἐκεῖνος masculine?
ὅταν δὲ ἔλθῃ ἐκεῖνος, τὸ πνεῦμα τῆς ἀληθείας, ...
(from John 16:13, NA28)
The traditional trinitarian answer is because the Holy Spirit is a person himself, not a thing. Can it be answered any other way?

The short answer is "Yes"!
The usual answer is that "He" refers to the grammatically masculine Παράκλητος (parakletos = "advocate") in V7.  However, it is a long way back in the text before V13.
Now, while this sounds grammatically tidy, I do not believe it fully explains the apparent grammatical-gender mismatch.  The construction in John 16:13 is:

But when He, the Spirit of truth, shall come, He will guide you
into all the truth. For He will not speak from Himself, but whatever
He may hear, He will speak. And He will declare to you the things
coming.

In this verse, the "He" (masculine) is explicit, emphatic, and demonstrative, viz, ἐκεῖνος  (ekeinos); and is in apposition to the neuter τὸ Πνεῦμα, which makes the gender clash quite stark!
As if to repeat this "problem", John repeats the same thing in similar lines by using the reflexive pronoun, ἑαυτοῦ (= "Himself") which is decidedly masculine.
I cannot avoid the feeling that John is going to some lengths to emphasize two matters in the extended discussion of the Advocate in John 16, viz:

the Advocate is distinct and separate from either Jesus or the Father
the advocate is a person

I also note that the title "Spirit of Truth" is also used in John 14:17, 15:26, 1 John 4:6, and always in a way that makes the Spirit of Truth distinct from either the Father and the Son.
